# Azure Monitor: How to fetch UsedCapacity for particulare FileShare?

Tags: azure-files, azure-rest-api, azure-monitor

I'm trying to get the used Capacity from the Azure Monitor [REST-API](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported.md#microsoftclassicstoragestorageaccountsfileservices) for a particular Fileshare.

But all I get is the summarized Capacity. Does anymone know the trick?

This command will deliver the UsedCapacity for the entire StorageAccount:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<MYSUBSCRIPTION>/resourceGroups/<MYRG>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<MYSTORAGEACCOUNT>/fileServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the share usage by using the [Get Share Stats API: Get Share Stats (FileREST API) - Azure Files | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-share-stats)

[image]